# I want to maker a Forge Heat Map using my personal CSV files with a Revit Building

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge, autodesk-data-visualization

I hope you all are well. I have been trying to use the Forge reference application template to be able to make a heat map for a building (I have the .RVT file for it).

However, whenever I try to run this [github.com/weshinchman/forge-dataviz-testrepo](https://github.com/weshinchman/forge-dataviz-testrepo) it just displays the following page on my local host.

Please let me know if you have had similar problems or if you know how to fix this. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Please see the snapshot I shared here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72951088/7745569

The CSV settings in `.env` file work without any problem on my side.

```
ADAPTER_TYPE=csv
#CSV_MODEL_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/device-models.json
#CSV_DEVICE_JSON=server/gateways/synthetic-data/devices.json
#CSV_FOLDER=server/gateways/csv/
CSV_DATA_START=2011-02-01T08:00:00.000Z
CSV_DATA_END=2011-02-20T13:51:10.511Z
#CSV_DELIMITER="\t"
#CSV_LINE_BREAK="\n"
#CSV_TIMESTAMP_COLUMN="time"
#CSV_FILE_EXTENSION=".csv"
```

To make the app work with more sensors, you must add individual CVS files named with the device ids of [devices.json](https://github.com/weshinchman/forge-dataviz-testrepo/blob/main/server/gateways/synthetic-data/devices.json) to `server/gateways/csv`. For example, the `Hyperion-1.csv` is for the below device.

```
{
    "id": "Hyperion-1",
    "name": "Conference 103",
    "position": {
        "x": "26",
        "y": " -63",
        "z": " -9.6"
    },
    "lastActivityTime": "2020-10-15T02:43:06.4432973Z"
},
```

For `Hyperion-24`, you must have a CSV file named as `Hyperion-24.csv` under `server/gateways/csv`.